# Determine the joint density function $f(x,y)$ for $0<y<1$ and $x>0$

Tags: probability, statistics

> The continuous random variables X and Y have the joint distribution function
>   $$F(x,y)=\begin{cases}1-e^{-x} & y>1 ,\:x>0\\y(1-e^{-x}) & 0<y<1,\:x > 0\\0 & else\end{cases}$$
>   Determine the joint density function $f(x,y)$ for $0<y<1$ and $x>0$

Usually to go from the distribution function to the density function I differentiate the distribution function, but in this case I have the joint so it depends on $x$ and $y$, how can I calculate the joint density function? Also because the interval $x>0$ is present in $2$ cases, how can I deal with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply differentiate with respect to both variables, i.e. $$\frac{\partial F(x,y)}{\partial x \partial y}=\begin{cases}0 & y>1 ,\:x>0\\e^{-x} & 0<y<1,\:x > 0\\0 & else\end{cases}$$
The answer might seem counter-intuitive but inspect the joint CDF. When $y>1$, $F(x,y)=P(X\leq x, Y \leq y)$ doesn't change with respect to $y$, i.e. there is no volume for $y$, when $y>1$.

Comment: You are right, thank you a lot for the answer! :)